# Use font from React Native assets in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, swiftui

Is it possible to access files inside my React Native project in Swift(UI)?
Lets say I have a custom font which lives inside my app/assets/fonts folder in React Native. This font is linked so it is visible in the info.plist inside Xcode, however it isn't listed when using

```swift
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
     let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
     print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

Do I have to copy the font over to the Xcode project? Resulting in having double the amount of assets. Isn't there a better way to do this?

This doesn't apply to only fonts, but also images and icons that live inside the assets folder that I might want to use in a Native Module.

Comment: As far as I am aware if you want to use items in native modules they have to be in the native part. There isn’t a way to bridge them across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Xcode automatically creates a reference to the files when you drag them into your project (when possible?). So the font inside my assets directory from my React Native project will be 'called' instead of creating a copy. All good!